# File Not Found Exception when calling openAssetFileDescriptor

Tags: android

I am reading the bitmap like this. I am picking the pick from the Gallery and gettting exception. Please help me to solve this.

```
// Read bitmap
    public Bitmap readBitmap(Uri selectedImage) {
        Bitmap bm = null;
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize = 5;
        AssetFileDescriptor fileDescriptor =null;
        try {
            fileDescriptor = this.getContentResolver().openAssetFileDescriptor(selectedImage,"r");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
            try {
                bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor(), null, options);
                fileDescriptor.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return bm;
    }
```

Log Trace :

```
06-13 14:05:11.470: W/System.err(20799): java.io.FileNotFoundException: No such file or directory
    06-13 14:05:11.470: W/System.err(20799):    at android.os.Parcel.openFileDescriptor(Native Method)
    06-13 14:05:11.470: W/System.err(20799):    at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.open(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:117)
    06-13 14:05:11.480: W/System.err(20799):    at android.content.ContentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor(ContentResolver.java:609)
    06-13 14:05:11.480: W/System.err(20799):    at com.example.Main.readBitmap(Main.java:416)
    06-13 14:05:11.480: W/System.err(20799):    at com.example.Main.addContents(Main.java:315)
    06-13 14:05:11.480: W/System.err(20799):    at com.example.Main.sendMMS(Main.java:231)
    06-13 14:05:11.480: W/System.err(20799):    at com.example.Main.access$16(Main.java:228)
    06-13 14:05:11.480: W/System.err(20799):    at com.example.Main$AsyncNetworkOperation.doInBackground(Main.java:397)
    06-13 14:05:11.490: E/Trace(23274): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
    06-13 14:05:11.490: D/ActivityThread(23274): setTargetHeapUtilization:0.25
    06-13 14:05:11.490: D/ActivityThread(23274): setTargetHeapIdealFree:8388608
    06-13 14:05:11.490: D/ActivityThread(23274): setTargetHeapConcurrentStart:2097152
```

Comment: what is the directory?

Comment: file:///mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/2013-06-08%2022.18.06.jpg

Comment: Well I never actually did what your trying to do, but I suppose that you need some permissions for accessing your photos from the gallery.